dsnless connection using oracledb
Using VBA I can make a dsnless connection to oracle in the following way.
Driver={Oracle in OraClient21Home1};DBQ=<<string_returned_from_tnsping>>;User Id=fake_user;Password=fake_password;

Is there a similar way I can do the same in Python with oracledb?

Not sure what you mean by "dnsless" or "the following way". What does your python documentation say about how to construct an Oracle connection?


Use Thick mode with libraries from your Oracle Database home
Don't pass a DSN parameter when connecting; this will pick up the environment ORACLE_SID

import os
import platform

import oracledb

ld = None  # On Linux, pass None
if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    ld = str(os.environ.get('HOME'))+'/Downloads/instantclient_23_3'
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
    ld = r'C:\oracle\instantclient_19_23'
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=ld)
print('Using Thick mode')

un = 'cj'
pw = 'cj'

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """select systimestamp from dual"""
        for (r,) in cursor.execute(sql):
            print(r)

This actually also works with Instant Client to a remote database if you set the old Oracle environment variable TWO_TASK to your connect string.
